# Css keep table width remain the same while user hit ctrl + on chrome to increase font size

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

When user press ctrl ++ on keyboard to increase the size of font of my webpage, I want the table width remain the same so that my website won't have scroll bar at bottom. Is it possible to write css or javascript to prevent table width increase when user hit ctrl ++ ? Thanks.

Comment: have you attempted a solution?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put a bit of your code up on jsfiddle or codepen. If you have set a pixel width of the table, then the answer is no, you cannot prevent that. If you have set width as a percentage, such as 100%, then the content should flow down vertically.

Comment: please also consider the usability, people often zoom for accessibility reasons, don't mess up their experience :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `width: 100%;` (as a maximum, though you may want some other, smaller percentage)

What happens when the browser zooms is basically the same as viewing the website on a device with a smaller screen. The font does increase in size, but only because the css pixel quantity decreases. Media queries come into play as well as other css layout properties being treated accordingly. A width 100% or less will never be wider than it's container.

See the [example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vLomgdra/4/)

The first div stays in the container (which can be the screen) whereas the second, with fixed width, expands outside it

You'll also notice on zooming that the panels in JSFiddle also react in the same way.

PS: you might want to build [some media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) that handles the display of the table at different sizes. This way you can take complete control of the experience and give users a nicely rendered table regardless of their zoom level or device screen size.